# leaks in my C program i need to free all the leaks in my functions (except in the main , thats on the caller)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

i'm writing a function (get_next_line) that returns a line read from a file descriptor, so i have the line stored in a char array that i return, now i need to process this line
so i read values into a buffer, whenever there are values read, the buffer should be processed, the newly added values should be joined with the result char array, if however, we encounter a newline, an extra step is required, i append the characters to the resulting array, until i reach the newline, which will be replaced by a null char, then the remaining values in the buffer should be stored in a static array that will append those values to the resulting string next time gnl is called.

the output of my function is correct my i need to deal with the leaks , i solved all of the leaks except the one related to the static char. btw im only allowed to use read() malloc() and free , all the other functions should be made by me (that explains the ft_ before each function in my code) here is my code :
[valgrind results for the leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNnVy.png)

```c
#include "get_next_line.h"

char * get_next_line(int fd) {

   // // the reminder will contain the values after '\n' because  the function should let
 // you read the text file one line at a time. for example if the the buffer size is 5 and
  // the first line is abc\nz we need to store the 'z' for the next line. 
  static char *reminder = "";
  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
  int nbytes;
  char * line = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
  if (!line || reminder == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (fd < 0 || fd > 999) {
    free(line);
    return NULL;
  }

  while ((nbytes = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
    buf[nbytes] = '\0';
     // ft_strjoin allocates and returns a new
      // string, which is the result of the concatenation of ’s1’ and ’s2’.

    reminder = ft_strjoin(reminder, buf);
     //i modified strchr to returns a pointer to the character after '\n'
    if (ft_strchr(reminder, '\n')) {
      
      // each line from the txt file start from the index 0 to '\n'
      line = ft_substr(reminder, 0, '\n');
      reminder = ft_strchr(reminder, '\n');
      return line;
    }
  }
  if (ft_strcmp(reminder, "") == 0 || nbytes < 0 || reminder == NULL) {
    free(line);
    return NULL;
  }

   if ((!(ft_strchr(reminder, '\n')))) {
      ptr = reminder;
      reminder = NULL;
      return ptr;
 }

   if (ft_strchr(reminder, '\n')) {
      ptr = ft_substr(reminder, 0, '\n');
      reminder = ft_strchr(reminder, '\n');
      return ptr;
 }
  return NULL;
}
// here is my strjoin
    char    *ft_strjoin(char  *s1, char  *s2)
{
    size_t  size_s1;
    size_t  size_s2;
    char    *strjoin;

    size_s1 = ft_strlen(s1);
    size_s2 = ft_strlen(s2);
    if (!(strjoin = malloc(size_s1 + size_s2 + 1)))
        return (NULL);
    ft_strcpy(strjoin, s1);
    ft_strcat(strjoin, s2);
    if(!(ft_strcmp(s1, "") == 0))
    {
        free(s1);
     }
    return (strjoin);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. That is, include the `main` and any other code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `reminder = ft_strjoin(reminder, buf);` Whenever you overwrite `reminder` you are leaking the previous pointer. Call `free(reminder)` before overwriting the old pointer. There are also some places where it looks like you should be using a seperate temp pointer rather than overwriting `reminder`.

Comment: @kaylum but i can't free reminder its a static variable , the content would be lost for the next call , should i create another char pointer and use it instead of reminder ?

Comment: "*should i create another char pointer and use it instead of reminder*". Yes, probably. You must not overwrite/change `reminder` without first freeing it. So if you need to operate on the string contents then should use a seperate pointer variable.